# Como saber y restablecer el nivel de zoom en Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows, terminal

Estoy usando Windows Terminal recientemente, y durante video llamadas uso `Ctrl+` para hacer zoom a la ventana, y `Ctrl-` para volver al tamano original, bueno eso espero, mi pregunta se como saber si el nivel edl zoom, o mejor aun como restablecerlo al tamano original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presiona Ctrl + 0 (es decir, mantén presionada la tecla Ctrl y presiona 0 en la fila superior del teclado) para restablecer el nivel de zoom al tamaño original.